# Nested IIF/Lookup

Tags: function, reporting, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

I'm brand new to SQL, SSRS, and Report Builder.

I am trying to compare three separate datasets 1. poreceipts (this is all purchase orders and items received by the company) 2. moat (this is all descriptive data available at the item level) and 3. production (this is a data dump that has info on items and usage, so it overlaps quite a bit with the other two datasets).

What I first needed to do was create a function that would let me check ITEM_ID.Value (from poreceipts) against Sku.Value (from moat) and return Series_Desc.Value (from moat).  Which looks like this:

=Lookup(Fields!ITEM_ID.Value, Fields!Sku.Value, Fields!Series_Desc.Value, "moat")

Unfortunately the Series_Desc field for a number of items is blank.  That's where the third dataset comes in.  I need to be able to check if the value is blank, if it isn't than it returns Series_Desc.Value... If it is blank, then I need to lookup ITEM_ID.Value against BASE_ITEM.Value (from dataset production) in order to return COATED_ITEM_ID.Value (again from dataset production) which then needs to be used to lookup Sku.Value and return Series_Desc.Value (from moat).

Phew... that was a mouthful, and hopefully it's somewhat clear.

Thank you all in advance!

-K

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, then you only need one dataset and let the database server do the lookups for you. The query for your dataset should look somewhat similar to this:

```
SELECT po.*, ISNULL(m.Series_Desc, m2.Series_Desc) AS Series_Desc
FROM poreceipts po
  LEFT OUTER JOIN moat m ON po.ITEM_ID = m.Sku
  LEFT OUTER JOIN poreceipts b ON po.BASE_ITEM = b.ITEM_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN moat m2 ON b.COATED_ITEM_ID = m2.Sku;
```